# Como saber se usuário está logado com ion-auth 2

Tags: php, codeigniter, autenticação

Quero restringir o acesso ao meu sistema de login, para apenas 1 para cada login, quero que meu sistema bloqueie o acesso, caso o login já esteja sendo utilizado em outro dispositivo.

Qual seria a melhor pratica pra fazer isso?

Estou utilizando Codeigniter 3, junto com o plugins Ion-Auth 2.
url do plugns https://github.com/benedmunds/CodeIgniter-Ion-Auth.

Answer (score 1):

Então, o problema que você quer resolver é que o mesmo usuário não pode estar logado em duas "máquinas" ao mesmo tempo.

Usando sessões normais, que ficam no servidor - seja em memória ou no banco de dados - você só tem uma certeza: o seu usuário se autenticou no sistema. Você não tem como descobrir se ele ainda está logado ou não, a menos que ele te informe expressamente - ou seja: tenha pedido para deslogar.

Para saber se o cara ainda está logado, basta na hora do login verificar se o email/login dele está no banco de dados onde você guarda a sessão (um `SELECT email FROM session WHERE email = $email` já resolve). O problema é que você pode acabar travando seu usuário fora do seu sistema até a sessão vencer.

No entanto, tem uma forma de você saber se ele ainda está usando o sistema, se a aba ainda está aberta no navegador dele: você vai usar um `websocket` no lado cliente e do servidor. Não vou me prolongar na implementação do cliente, mas encontrei um [tutorial que parece bom](https://www.html5rocks.com/pt/tutorials/websockets/basics/) sobre essa parte.

Pensa em `WebSocket` como uma sala de chat com o servidor, seu cliente pode mandar mensagens pro servidor e o servidor pode mandar mensagens pro cliente e/ou clientes.

O problema, é que esse tutorial não tem a parte da implementação do servidor `WebSocket` - por que o que você já tem é um servidor web, `HTTP`. Uma biblioteca que encontrei para PHP é o [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). Você, literalmente, vai precisar rodar um outro server - em outra porta - para receber as mensagens do cliente. No `Ratchet` seria algo como:

```
class WSAuth implements MessageComponentInterface {
    public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
        // Store the new connection to send messages to later
        $this->clients->attach($conn);

        echo "New connection! ({$conn->resourceId})\n";
    }

    public function onMessage(ConnectionInterface $from, $msg) {
        // recebe a mensagem do cliente com login e senha
        // faz toda a verificação para autenticá-lo
        // manda o SessionID de volta pro cliente, e guarda o cookie.
    }

    public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
       // desloga o usuário caso o cliente tenha se conectado antes
    }

    public function onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e) {
      // provavelmente você deve deslogar o cara se der erro também
    }
}
```

---

Outra solução seria ficar mandando um Ajax à cada minuto pro servidor e se o cliente não mandar por 3 minutos você desloga ele.

Answer (score 0):

Consultando a [documentação](http://benedmunds.com/ion_auth/) do ion_auth você pode ver que tem um método `logged_in()` da própria biblioteca. Retorna `TRUE` caso esteja logado.

Comment: Essa função não retorno o que preciso, essa função vai verificar se está logado e dai mando o usuário para pagina restrita, o que quero e não deixar o usuário logar 2 vezes com mesmo login e senha

Comment: nesse caso você precisaria salvar a sessão no banco de dados e na hora de fazer um login verificar se o usuário não está na sessão do banco;

Comment: @DaniloD mas aí como ele vai saber se o cara se logou e perdeu a sessão dele? Por exemplo, se ele se logou e entrou em outro navegador ou no celular.

Acho que o que o @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão quer pode ser alguma questão de segurança mais complexa nesse caso. Seria preciso algum tipo de verificação constante da validade da sessão. A melhor maneira de manter isso seria por ``WebSockets``.

Comment: @Daniel mas a sessão é global no banco de dados, [documentação](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html#database-driver) ele poderia informar na sessão o e-mail no usuário no campo 'data'. ai logando antes de logar ele verificava se aquele e-mail tava no campo data, se tivesse é por que ele logou, mesmo que seja em um dispositivo diferente.

Comment: É acho que alguma coisa no que o @Daniel disse. a session do Codeigniter já gravada no banco, mais se ela expirar, é bem isso que ele falou meus usuários vão acessar por celular, tablet e computador, só não vai ser permitido o acesso com mesmo login mais de uma vez, se ele estiver logado, não pode logar com mesmo login em navegadores diferente, ou em dispositivos diferente.

Comment: @ClaytonEduardoMergulhão então, edita sua pergunta pra ela ficar mais certinha, aí preparo uma resposta explicando por alto como fazer verificação de sessão usando ``WebSockets``. Que eu nem sei bem, mas já vi na teoria. Só que não vou considerar o ion_auth, por que é mais geral que isso.

Comment: @Daniel veja se ficou melhor a pergunta?